# How to make SVG textPath work in div background-image via CSS?

Tags: css, svg, background-image

How to make SVG textPath work in div background-image via CSS ?
[Here is my working craft on CodePen](https://codepen.io/o-k-s-a-n-a/pen/vVKyrQ)

This code works in HTML version, but doesn't in CSS.

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg id='decorative-text-link' role='link' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 100 10'%3E %3Cdefs%3E %3Cpath id='squiggle_link_text' style='stroke:none'; fill='none' d='M0,3.5 c 5,0,5,-3,10,-3 s 5,3,10,3 c 5,0,5,-3,10,-3 s 5,3,10,3'/%3E %3C/defs%3E %3Cg style='font-family:Lato; font-size:.1rem'%3E %3Cuse xlink:href='#squiggle_link_text'/%3E %3Ctext%3E %3CtextPath xlink:href='#squiggle_link_text'%3EThere is a link%3C/textPath%3E %3C/text%3E %3C/g%3E %3C/svg%3E");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your SVG, a stray ; outside the attribute quotes instead of inside.

You've also not URL encoded the # characters which is invalid per the appropriate specifications and won't work in Firefox.

I've corrected these issues below.

```css
html, body, div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg id='decorative-text-link' role='link' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 100 10'%3E %3Cdefs%3E %3Cpath id='squiggle_link_text' style='stroke:none;' fill='none' d='M0,3.5 c 5,0,5,-3,10,-3 s 5,3,10,3 c 5,0,5,-3,10,-3 s 5,3,10,3'/%3E %3C/defs%3E %3Cg style='font-family:Lato; font-size:.1rem'%3E %3Cuse xlink:href='%23squiggle_link_text'/%3E %3Ctext%3E %3CtextPath xlink:href='%23squiggle_link_text'%3EThere is a link%3C/textPath%3E %3C/text%3E %3C/g%3E %3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Longson for your clear explanation and this code correction!